# Issue in Import database .sql file to WAMP server (MySQL Version 5.5.24)

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, wamp

I had take my database backup in WAMP server (MySQL Version **5.0.10**)

This database is use PK-FK realtionship between multiple tables each others.

Now when i Import this backup.sql file in my new wamp server phpmyadmin (i.e **5.0.10** => **5.5.24**); it shows dependency error; that `Unknown column 'min_investment_size' in 'field list'` when first Dumping data for table `company`.

I know here **`company`** table have one FK relationship with **`investment`**  table; so before dumping `company` table how to dump it's predecessor table on which company is relies?

Also many other tables and procedure have same depedency issue. E.g. user need `company.id`; so even before dumping user table company table must be dumped. Some screenshots here i want to share:

[image]
[image]

So how to par from this situtation.

Note: I have already tried to migrate with

1. RedGate MySQL Comparator.
2. MySQL workbench

but the error during migration/synchronization is same as above.

Comment: The simple answer is to `turn off Foreign Key Checking` in the restore. You do this by checking an option on the Export `Disable foreign key checks` when you create the dump to use to restore to the new version of MySQL.

Comment: Still there is error: procedure_name already exist

Answer (score 1):

1) the table structure in db does not have the column

2) the stored proc already exists and your script doesn't do an if before it to create it only if it does not exist

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mysql.proc p WHERE db = 'db_name' AND name = 'stored_proc_name') THEN
   {your stored proc block here} 
END IF;
```

or drop if exist on spname then create it

Comment: I have taken whole backup at once. And try to import that .sql file. No separate imports

Comment: I am not there. that is what it is reporting. Look at table structure. Look at proc existence prior to that part. It seems straight forward to me. Stuff is already there (sp), table is different structure

Comment: Before importing database nothing is there; only fresh empty db

Comment: then create a mini-script with everything prior to the first failure. run it. see what you have before you run the thing that fails. When I run a script, I don't think, oh this is definitely going to work. I expect it to fail

Comment: if you want to post your script on google drive or somewhere, would be glad to check it out for you. good luck

Comment: @Drew: try to encourage the OP to put everything in the question if they can. I appreciate there are rare occasions when it's not practical, but we want to default to self-contained here, so that future readers can learn something even if links break.

Comment: i am totally with you. this seems different and the OP seems flustered. I would do it, then document here myself (ie: edit OP question directly). Of course Vegas says that will never happen. Like to call a bluff now and then @halfer

Comment: Heh, fair enough @Drew `:-)`

Comment: @Drew I have follow these steps 1. Export whole db from my live server(including SP+Structure+data) 2. .sql file is imported to my localhost database. Note: Same .sql file is able to import in my DEV server which have same version as LIVE server. I have also try with MySQL Compare tool and with MySQL Workbench

Comment: and what happened ? on DEV server success? on localhost failure ?